# Angular model not updating view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to display a variable when it comes available, but it isn't showing.
It only shows when I call the function again with a button click.
Not using $scope in my code. And did some (maybe) weird things to try and make it work.

Can anyone figure out why it's not showing immidiately?

Html:

```
    <body ng-app="LocApp">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>

    <info>

    </info>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('LocApp', [])
    .directive('info', function infoDirective(){

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            template: '<button ng-click="LocaCtrl.getLoc()">Get location</button><h1>{{LocaCtrl.dif | number:2}}</h1><h3 style="color: red;">{{LocaCtrl.error}}</h3>',
            bindToController: {
                dif: '<',
                error: '<'
            },
            require: ['info'],
            controller: function(){
                console.log('test');

                var controller = this;
                controller.dif = 0;

                controller.toRad = function(val){
                    return val * Math.PI / 180;
                };

                controller.calcDif = function(lat1, lon1){
                    console.log("Latitude:", lat1);
                    console.log("Longitude:", lon1);

                    var lat2 = 52.099233999999996;
                    var lon2 = 5.0651474;

                    var R = 6371e3; // metres
                    var rad1 = controller.toRad(lat1);
                    var rad2 = controller.toRad(lat2);
                    var deltRad = controller.toRad(lat2-lat1);
                    var deltLamb = controller.toRad(lon2-lon1);

                    var a = Math.sin(deltRad/2) * Math.sin(deltRad/2) +
                            Math.cos(rad1) * Math.cos(rad2) *
                            Math.sin(deltLamb/2) * Math.sin(deltLamb/2);
                    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));   
                    return R * c;
                };

                controller.getLoc = function(){
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                        let lat1 = position.coords.latitude;
                        let lon1 = position.coords.longitude;
                        controller.dif = controller.calcDif(lat1, lon1);
                        console.log("dif",controller.dif);
                    }, function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                };
            },
            controllerAs: 'LocaCtrl',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){
                ctrls[0].getLoc();
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: i think you have not added your directive JS file in you HTML file.

Comment: Its working as expected see this http://plnkr.co/edit/tkoW8Icuam4BEdxmY6En?p=preview

Comment: @VinodLouis It is showing the initial value, but it isn't updating it with the new value from the function I run at the start

Comment: check console where you calls resolves values or not

Comment: @VinodLouis Data is showing in the console when it is available.

Comment: @Kuiken try $apply because navigator is not inside scope of angular

Comment: @VinodLouis That was it! I thought $scope.$apply() could only be used on $scope vriables, but it can be used to wrap other ajax calls as well. Thanks

Comment: yeah I was also mistaken initially thinking with the name `controller` but then seeing navigator realized that scope is changed outside the context of angular :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was advised to use $apply. I thought it was a thing to update $scope variables, but that's not how it works. 
$apply is called by angular every time a native angular ajax call, event or timeout is called. All the affected variables are updated to the view.

$apply is not called on not native ajax calls like my location api call.
So it has to be called manually to update the view with the new values.

so by calling $scope.$apply(function(){my code} it was updated :D

Thanks to Vinod for making me look closer at the documentation.